# SAS/SCSI Errors in Syslog: Kernel FAILED

Tags: linux, sas, scsi, slackware

I have a Dell 2950 2U rackmount server with 3 146GB SAS drives in a RAID array, running Slackware 10.2 (an old version, I know). Recently I am seeing these errors in my /var/log/syslog repeating very often (constantly):

```
kernel: FAILED
kernel:   status = 1, message = 00, host = 0, driver = 08
kernel:   <6>sd: Current: sense key=0x5
```

lspci|grep RAID returns:

```
02:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Dell PowerEdge Expandable RAID controller 5
```

I realize this is most likely a SCSI/hdd error of some sort, but I was wondering if anyone knows of any ways I can trouble shoot this more to find out what exactly is going on.